# Flutter : InternalError , Filter error, bad data when upload image on server

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I do simple upload image to server using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) packages. But the problem is , when i upload it i got error `Unhandled Exception: InternalError: 'Filter error, bad data'`.

#### Upload

```
Future testUpload(File selfieImage, String pembertang) async {
    final result = await reusableRequestServer.requestServer(() async {
      //create multipart request for POST or PATCH method
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('$baseApiUtang/addUtang'));
      //add text fields
      request.fields['pembertang'] = '$pembertang';
      //create multipart using filepath, string or bytes
      var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('selfie', selfieImage.path);
      //add multipart to request
      request.files.add(pic);
      var response = await request.send();

      //Get the response from the server
      var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
      var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
      print('responseData : $responseData');
      print('responseString : $responseString');
      return responseString;
    });
    return result;
  }
```

With this strange problem , i try it with postman but it's work like i want.
[image]

 My opinion, it's not problem in my backend code. I missed something ?

#### Update

Similiar problem with me on this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32558)

#### Update 2

When i look inside the code and print variable 1 by 1, i got status code **403**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you pls try following code

```
 var stream = new http.ByteStream(Stream.castFrom(imageFile.openRead()));
    // get file length
    var length = await imageFile.length();
    // create multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var name = firstname +"."+imageFile.path.split(".").last;
    // multipart that takes file
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('profile', stream, length,
        filename: basename(name));
```

In my case my can not take so much long name so i customise image name and then tried and its working .
so you can also try this.

Comment: `DelegatingStream.typed` it deprecated

Comment: use Stream.castFrom instead